# onclick submit button not returning javascript function yii

Tags: javascript, yii

My code is in the

**view**

```
<?php echo CHtml::SubmitButton('Submit',array('onclick'=>'return validation();'));?>
```

and **my script function** is

```
function validation(){

    jQuery("#firstname_result").hide();

    jQuery("#lastname_result").hide();

    jQuery("#email_result").hide();

var firstname =jQuery("#first_name").val();

    var lastname = jQuery("#last_name").val();

    var email = jQuery("#email").val();

success=true;

if(firstname==''){

    success=false;

    jQuery('#firstname_result').html('First Name cannot be blank.').show();


}
if(lastname==''){
        success=false;
    jQuery('#lastname_result').html('Last Name cannot be blank.').show();

}
if(email==''){    
        success=false;
    jQuery('#email_result').html('Email cannot be blank.').show();

}

if(!success)
        return;

}
```

after clicking submit button, shows error and flashed out to other page where submit is targeted..can any one show me the way how I can able to overcome from this?

Comment: should you not be returning the value of `success`? At the moment it looks like you're not returning anything?

Comment: Not as an answer... remember four spaces before your code. Right now, it looks ugly:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning the value of the success variable. it should do the trick.

```
if(!success) return;
```

should be

```
return success;
```

this will stop the form from sumitting.

Answer (score 0):

Use preventDefault to prevent form submitiion.

Modified code:

```
<?php echo CHtml::SubmitButton('Submit',array('onclick'=>'return validation(event);'));?>

function validation(event){
   ..... //code 
  if(!success) {  
         event.preventDefault();
         event.returnValue = false; // for IE.
     }
```